# How to query Api.ai using postman

Tags: rest, postman, dialogflow-es

I have with me access token to query Api.ai. How to use postman get and post method. Should I create Oautho 2.0?

Comment: Hi @sarath if the answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Answer (score 0):

You need to include it in the header values like so:

```
Authorization:Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Reference: https://api.ai/docs/reference/agent/